How to access the Google Analytics Data API via bash script using gcloud
On a Ubuntu server I want to regularly execute a script which calls the Google Analytics Data API in order to extract the 20 most visited pages of a website.

I have successfully installed the gcloud CLI (Google Cloud CLI) on my Ubuntu 24 server.
I have created a service account in my Google Cloud Account and a assigned a Google created secret Key to it and downloaded the key.json file (used for authentication later).
In the relevant Google Analytics Admin section i created a new user (with the email address of the service account) that has at least read permission to the analytics data.

According to the Google Cloud CLI Documentation i created the following bash script:
#!/bin/bash

# Set environment variables
export KEY_FILE="/home/yesitsme/utilities/scripts/gcloud.json"
export PROPERTY_ID="278767000"

# Authenticate using the service account
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=$KEY_FILE

# Get access token
ACCESS_TOKEN=$(gcloud auth print-access-token)

# Make API request for page views in the last 24 hours
curl -X POST \
  "https://analyticsdata.googleapis.com/v1beta/properties/$PROPERTY_ID:runReport" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{
        "dateRanges": [
          {
            "startDate": "yesterday",
            "endDate": "today"
          }
        ],
        "dimensions": [
          {
            "name": "pagePath"
          }
        ],
        "metrics": [
          {
            "name": "screenPageViews"
          }
        ],
        "limit": 5
      }'

If i execute the gcloud auth command only, i see that the access token gets created successfully.
But when executing the script, i get this output with an error:
Activated service account credentials for: [zwischengas-google-cloud-api@zwischengas.iam.gserviceaccount.com]
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "method": "google.analytics.data.v1beta.BetaAnalyticsData.RunReport",
          "service": "analyticsdata.googleapis.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

So the question is clear: why does my newly created service account have not enough permissions? Any hint?

I think the issue is that the Service Account has insufficient OAuth Scopes for Google Analytics. There are probably better ways but I've always used the obscure-but-useful oauth2l for this purpose. Instead (!) of gcloud auth activate-service-account and ACCESS_TOKEN=$(gcloud auth print-access-token), you should (!?) be able to ACCESS_TOKEN=$(oauth2l fetch --credentials=${KEY_FILE} --scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics).

You can verify this behavior by taking ACCESS_TOKEN=$(gcloud auth print-access-token) (your original credentials) and browsing https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=${ACCESS_TOKEN}, this should have the default Cloud Platform scopes and not Google Analytics. Then use the ACCESS_TOKEN value using oauth2l .... and you should see Google Analytics scope.

You can also use oauth2l to view token scopes: oauth2l info --token ${ACCESS_TOKEN}

Why is Google not officially mentioning oauth2l in all their documentation when it comes to retrieve data from Google Analytics Data API?

It's not specific to Google Analytics. It's a general-purpose tool for working with Google credentials, tokens and scopes. There are probably better ways to achieve the same result but that's the way I know/prefer.

Thanks to the hint of @DazWilkin i found a working solution. Here is what I have done:

In the Google Cloud Console, setup a new Service Account and let Google create the secret.json (login credentials containing the private key)
In the Google Cloud Console, enable the Google Analytics Data API
Write down your Google Analytics Property ID
Install gcloud on your server, initialize it with gcloud init and configure the newly created service account.
Install oauth2l on your server (https://github.com/google/oauth2l), verify it by executing oauth2l --help

Here is the full shell script that accesses your Google Analytics:
#!/bin/bash

# Set variables
KEY_FILE="/home/myuser/gcloud-service-account-secret.json"
PROPERTY_ID="27yy67xxx"
SCOPE="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly"

# Get an access token
ACCESS_TOKEN=$(oauth2l fetch --credentials=$KEY_FILE --scope=$SCOPE)

# Check if token retrieval was successful
if [ -z "$ACCESS_TOKEN" ]; then
  echo "Failed to retrieve access token"
  exit 1
fi

# Query Google Analytics Data API
curl -s -X POST \
  "https://analyticsdata.googleapis.com/v1beta/properties/$PROPERTY_ID:runReport" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{
        "dateRanges": [
          {
            "startDate": "yesterday",
            "endDate": "today"
          }
        ],
        "dimensions": [
          {
            "name": "pagePath"
          }
        ],
        "metrics": [
          {
            "name": "screenPageViews"
          }
        ],
  "dimensionFilter": {
         "orGroup": {
            "expressions": [
              {
                "filter": {
                  "fieldName": "pagePath",
                  "stringFilter": {
                    "matchType": "BEGINS_WITH",
                    "value": "/path1_i_want_to_include/"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "filter": {
                  "fieldName": "pagePath",
                  "stringFilter": {
                    "matchType": "BEGINS_WITH",
                    "value": "/path2/i/want/to_include/"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
  },
        
        "limit": 50
      }'

The result is simply a JSON file that you can store on disk and further process with your backend software.
